# Calling java rest api on different domain from Word Web addin

Tags: javascript, office-js

I am creating a Word Web Add-in (javascript). I need to `POST` to a Java API from the add-in. I am getting the below error when making the ajax request:

```
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.
```

When I track it through Fiddler, I see:

```
Redirect for CORS preflight is not allowed
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005
```

My ajax call is:

```
$.ajax({
    "async": false,
    "crossDomain": false,    
    "url": "https://qa.dev.com:8443/web/check/",    
    "method": "POST",
    "data": d,
    "headers": {
        "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    },
    "success": function (res) {
        console.log(res)
    },
    "error": function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(jqXHR.statusText);

    }
});
```

Comment: `"async": false,` — Don't do that, it is deprecated.

Comment: `"crossDomain": false,` — Why are you doing that? It clearly **is** cross-origin!

Comment: The error message "Redirect for CORS preflight is not allowed" seems pretty clear. What's the problem?

Comment: What does fiddler show for the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the server's response?

Comment: @Quentin The url  : qa.dev.com, is hosted on the local machine only from where i am making this request , so CORS error should not come.

Comment: @VarshaKhanna — The rules for determining if two origins the same are not "hosted on the same computer". That isn't even one of the rules, let alone all of them.

Comment: @Quentin Can you pls elaborate then other than including Access Control Allow Origin header in the response, how can it be achieved?

Comment: It says "Redirect for CORS preflight is not allowed" … so when you get the request for the preflight … don't respond with a redirect.

Comment: @Quentin : So change is to be done from the server side..Thanks!